# Connection between curvature and arc-length

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ be a curve in the plane. We can find its arc-length using the formula $$\ell=\int \sqrt{x^\prime (t)^2+y^\prime(t)^2}dt=\int\Vert r^\prime(t)\Vert dt.$$

We also can find the curvature of this curve. Denote by $v(t)=r^\prime(t)$ the tangent vector, one can express it as $$v(t)=\exp(i\theta(t))$$ getting equivalently $$\kappa_r(t)=|r^{\prime\prime}(t)|=\bigg\vert \frac{d\theta}{dt}\bigg\vert=\frac{|x'y''-y'x''|}{|r^\prime(t)|^3}.$$

In the special case of $ r(t)=(t,y(t)\, )$ we get the formula

$$\kappa=\dfrac{|y''|}{(1+y^{'2})^{1.5}}$$

That seems like the connection between the arc-length and the curvature has to be very strong. Can one express (even if $r(t)=(t,f(t))$) the curvature in terms of the arc-length?

Comment: Note that curvature _cannot_ be expressed purely in terms of arc length. One way to see this is to note that any two curves of the same length are diffeomorphic to each other by an arc-length-preserving diffeomorphism. The formula given by @DavidQuinn expresses curvature in terms of two quantities -- the arc length and the tangent angle.

Comment: For the connection see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272514/shouldnt-these-two-definitions-for-curvature-agree/1272699#1272699

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using intrinsic coordinates, yes. Curvature is then $$\kappa=\frac{d\psi}{ds}$$ where $\psi$ is the tangential angle and $s$ is arc length.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by intrinsic coordinates? Can one also write the signed curvature in intrinsic coordinates? If so: does it have similar expression?

Comment: Intrinsic coordinates are when the curve is expressed as $s=f(\psi)$. $\kappa$ changes sign according to the shape of the curve (convex to concave). For example, $s=c\tan \psi$ is the equation of a catenary.

Comment: Thanks. just to verify: $s(\tau)=\int_0^\tau \Vert r^\prime(t)\Vert dt$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: To add: the *Cesàro equation* for a curve expresses curvature as a function of arclength, while the *Whewell equation* for a curve expresses the tangential angle as a function of arclength.

Answer (score 2):

Denoting rotation by $\phi$ and arc by $t$,

$$\kappa= \frac{ d\phi}{dt}$$

By "strong" you mean $ natural, intrinsic, isometrically\, invariant $ etc.These depend upon first fundamental form and are therefore independent of euclidean motions of translation and rotation .. $x,y, \theta$. But all the above three  $ \phi,t $ and its derivative $\kappa$ are strong.

Examples of natural equation are $\kappa = 1$ ( unit Circle ) , $\kappa = t $ ( Cornu spiral) $ ,\kappa = \cos \phi $, (the Cycloid), movable *anywhere* in the $x-y$ plane, constants of integration are Euclidean motions.

In this notation $ \theta,\psi $ (polar coordinate rotation around origin and angle arc to radius vector ) are individually not "strong", but $ \theta + \psi $ is strong.

EDIT 1:

Only now it occurs to me. Instead of strong we could use *rigid*, as curvature and torsion are invariant in all Euclidean motions.